# xamarin.android visual studio for macCREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST: A fatalerror occured: Wrong classpath: error in opening zip file

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

when I'm building my project it's showing error as shown below  :

Errors:

/Users/muktigoutam/Documents/Projects/Dositrack/mobileappxamarin/Droid/DosiTrackMobile.Droid.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (_CompileToDalvikWithDx target) ->

```
CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST:  A fatalerror occured: Wrong classpath: error in opening zip file
```

please help  !!

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Did you ever figure out a solution?